# DDD + TELEFONE CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

Eu estou montando um cadastro, e nele eu preciso colocar um campo DDD e ao lado o telefone, para ficar deste jeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Versão Bootstrap: 3.3.7

Na documentação existe o `form-inline`, mas ele não como o esperado. Tentei ateé colocar a classe `col-xs-2` e `10`, mas os `inputs` ficam um por cima do outro.

```html
<!-- scripts -->

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">    
            <label> RG </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label><span style="color: red"> * </span> DDD </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label><span style="color: red"> * </span> Telefone </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Mais fácil colocar parte do código para que seja mais fácil para identificar o que esta ocorrendo

Comment: Felipe, talvez seja interessante você refazer o [tour], ler o guia de [ask] e acessar a [help], pois parece que entendeu errado algumas partes do funcionamento do site. Votos negativos não representam que sua pergunta é inútil, mas sim são apenas um indicativo que a sua pergunta está ruim e deve ser melhorada conforme os padrões definidos nos links anteriores. Você não postou o código HTML e quando postou o colocou como imagem. Isso é bem distante do que se recomenda como um [mcve]. Antes de ser sarcástico com quem votou na sua pergunta é interessante aprender a utilizar o site corretamente.

Comment: Se por acaso tiver alguma dúvida específica sobre o comportamento da comunidade ou do funcionamento do site que a [help] não foi suficientemente clara, você será bem-vindo no [meta], onde o objetivo é justamente debater sobre isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi qual foi a sua dificuldade, mas, é só fazer como está na [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline) e colocar o tamanho que quer o input nas classes de [grid](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
  <label for="rg">RG</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rg" placeholder="00000000">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-2">
  <label for="ddd">* DDD</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ddd" placeholder="00">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-10">
  <label for="tel">* TELEFONE</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tel" placeholder="00000-0000">
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado @LeAndrade

Comment: Por nada Felipe, como dito nos comentários acima, quando for realizar uma pergunta aqui no site, tente detalhar ao máximo o problema e se possível insira os códigos referentes ao problema. Successo!